# ObjectInputStream - StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00

Tags: java, serialization, corruption, objectinputstream

First off, I know that there are a number of questions on this exact exception, but none of them seem to have good answers.

I have a local network of clients communicating with a server over TCP sockets.  They are receiving large amounts of data from the server.  When I kick off my test, it runs fairly well for a while, but eventually I see this exception on one of the streams.

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1373)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
    at myProgram.connectionProtocol.waitForMsg(connectionProtocol.java:137)
    at myProgram.Client.ClientProcess$testController.run(ClientProcess.java:296)
    at myProgram.Client.ClientProcess.main(ClientProcess.java:71)
```

**UPDATE:**

**I've tried forcing each process to wait for an Acknowledge message before continuing, and sending a Resend if this error is encountered.  That adds a lot more complexity and seems to cause more problems than it fixes.**

**I added Buffered Streams (updated in the code) to all of the inputs, having heard that that will improve IO performance, but no luck.  It didn't cause problems though, so I'll leave it in.**

Here's some of my code (with junk removed):

server:

```
private Socket client;
private String clientName = "?";
private Boolean threadActive = true;
private PublicKey clientKey;
private int timeout = 100;

ClientWorker(Socket sock) {
    client = sock;
}
public void run(){
    Object line;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;

    client.setSoTimeout(timeout);
    in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));
    out.flush();

    while(threadActive){

        Message msgOut = msgQueue.get(0);
        if(msgOut != null && msgOut.source.equals(clientName)){
            msgQueue.remove(0);
            msgOut.source = "broker";
            out.writeObject(secure.signObject(msgOut,privKey));
            out.flush();
            out.reset();
        } 

        try{
            line = in.readObject();
            handleMessage((SignedObject) line);
        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
            //no data currently in stream
        }
    }
    client.close();
}
```

client:

```
serverSock = new connectionProtocol(name,privKey);
socketNum = serverSock.getSocketNum("server");
serverSock.openSocket(socketNum);
serverSock.setSoTimeout(100);

while(isActive){
    // ERROR OCCURS IN NEXT LINE
    serverMsg = (SignedObject)serverSock.waitForMsg();
    if(serverMsg != null)
        handleMessage(brokerMsg);

    // messages are sent/received over other sockets here
}
serverSock.closeSocket();
```

Periodically, another thread will also call serverSock.sendMsg(Message).

connectionProtocol:

```
public void openSocket(int sockNum) throws IOException {
    socket = new Socket("localhost", sockNum);
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    out.flush();


    Message initMessage = new Message(name,"open");
    SignedObject sigMessage = security.signObject(initMessage, privKey);
    out.writeObject(sigMessage);
    out.flush();
    out.reset();

    socketActive = true;
}

public synchronized void closeSocket(){
    socketActive = false;
    Message closeMessage = new Message(name,"end");
    out.writeObject(security.signObject(closeMessage,privKey));
    out.flush();
    socket.close();
}

public synchronized Object waitForMsg() throws IOException {
    Object msg = null;
    try {
        // ERROR OCCURS ON NEXT LINE
        msg = in.readObject();
        return msg;
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        return null;
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return msg;
}

public synchronized void sendMsg(Message msg){
    out.writeObject(security.signObject(msg, privKey));
    out.flush();
    out.reset();
}
```

Comment: You should construct the ObjectOutputStream before, not after, the ObjectInputStream. Post the peer code. What happens inside the catch block for the read timeout?

Comment: What is peer code?  You mean the client side?  That should have been posted, but somehow got lost.  I'll try again.

Nothing happens if there is a timeout - that just means that there is no message in the stream, and it can cycle back again.

Comment: So what's the point of the timeout? Why not just block? I'm not convinced that `ObjectInputStream` is so well written that it can resume seamlessly after a timeout. If this problem only occurs after a timeout, that would explain it.

Comment: I added a comment - there are messages being sent and received through other sockets within the same loop.  I just didn't want to include all of the code not related to this problem.  There are timeouts occuring multiple times a second, so I can't rule it out completely, but I don't suspect that it's the problem since the exception occurs after a few minutes of operation.

Comment: @EJP, could you post your previous comment as an answer?  I tried putting the listening in a separate thread from the sending and just bocked, and it appears to have done the trick